# Unity3D with C# - Using Input field to answer question

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, input-field

I'm creating a unity quiz game using input fields.
How can I use text from an input field to match with an answer in a c# script?

Comment: Please add some code and more details so others can help more easily.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

hijinxbassist's example is good, however, i made an example that includes the other parts as well, like adding event listeners and declaring the fields.

Checking for single correct answer:

```cs
public Button submitAnswerBtn; // assign a UI button object in editor
public InputField answerInput; // assign a UI inputfield object in editor
private string a1_right_answer = "foo"; // make it public and edit the answer in editor if you like

private void Awake()
{
   // add event listener when button for submitting answer is clicked
   submitAnswerBtn.onClick.AddListener(() => {
      // validate the answer
      if(answerInput.text.ToLower() == a1_right_answer) {
         // success
         Debug.Log("Correct");
      } else {
         Debug.Error("Wrong");
      }
});
```

Checking for multiple correct answers:

```cs
public Button submitAnswerBtn; // assign a UI button object in editor
public InputField answerInput; // assign a UI inputfield object in editor

private string[] a1_right_answers = { "foo", "bar", "foo1", "bar1" }; // multiple right answers

private bool is_right_answer = false; // default value

private void Awake()
{
   // add event listener when button for submitting answer is clicked
   submitAnswerBtn.onClick.AddListener(() => {

      // loop through all the right answers
      for (int i = 0; i < a1_right_answers.Length; i++) 
      {
         // validate the answer
         if(answerInput.text.ToLower() == a1_right_answers[i]) {
            // success
            is_right_answer = true;
            break; 
         }
      }

      // check if the user got the right or wrong answer
      if(is_right_answer) { 
          Debug.Log("Correct");
          is_right_answer = false; // reset for next guess
      } 
      else {
          Debug.Log("Wrong");
          // no need to reset 'is_right_answer' since its value is already default
      }

});
```

Comment: Is it possible to make multiple right answers and not just check for one answer?

Comment: Yes, of course. I added extra code for that case as well in the answer.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure which part of this problem you are stuck on, but I will attempt to answer.

I think the most important thing when comparing an input field with a stored answer is to make sure the comparison is case insensitive.  You can do this by converting both texts to either lowercase or uppercase.

```
var usersAnswer = answerInputField.text.ToLower();
var actualAnswer = "Some Answer".ToLower();

if (usersAnswer == actualAnswer)
{
    Debug.Log("You got it right!");
}
```